# After impersonate with Passport.js, can't log back to the previous user

Tags: angularjs, node.js, passport.js, mean-stack

I have a NodeJS/Angular (MEAN) application in which I managed to impersonate another user (for admins).
I created a route `/auth/autolog/:userId` (`req.profile` contains the user with Id :userId):

```
exports.autolog = function (req, res) {
    req.login(req.profile, function (err) {
        if (err)
            return res.status(400).send(err);
        return res.send(req.profile);
    });
};
```

It works well, but I also want to be able to log back to my admin account. So I have a route `/auth/autolog/logback/:adminId`:

```
exports.logback = function (req, res) {
    if (req.profile.role > 1) {
        return res.status(401).send({err: 'You are not admin'});
    } else {
        req.login(req.profile, function (err) {
            if (err)
                return res.status(400).send(err);
            return res.send(req.profile);
        });
    }
};
```

It's the same code as the previous function plus a simple admin check.
But this one doesn't work. The return status is 200, everything seems to work, but Passport don't persist the new user Id in the Session in the database.
If I try to call many times (between 2 and 15) the Log Back, it will work.